# Add CSS classes to a panel in code behind

Tags: asp.net, css, panel, code-behind

i have a panel in aspx page that looks like that:

```
<asp:Panel ID="popUpPanelSelectFields" runat="server" CssClass="confirm-dialog" BorderColor="Aqua" >   
<div class="inner">
        <h2>hello word</h2>
        <div class="base">
            <br/>
            <asp:Label ID="LabelMessageToTeacher" runat="server" Text="some text" /><br/>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxMessageToTeacher" runat="server" Width="200px" Height="50px"/><br/><br/>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxSkype" runat="server" Text="some text" /><br/>                
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxPhoneNumber" runat="server" Text="some text" /><br/><br/>                                
            <asp:Button ID="ButtonOk" runat="server" Text="Ok" />
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

i want to write the same code in code behind but i have problems with the css
Code written so far:

```
Panel panel = new panel();
panel .CssClass = "confirm-dialog";
panel BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Aqua;
```

now i know how to add the labels,buttons,checkbox and textbox, but how can i add the "h2"
to the labels and wrap the controls with the "inner" and "base" classes from my css file

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the [`HtmlElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontrol%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class.

You would use it like any other control class to build up the element hierarchy on the page:

```
var div = new HtmlElement("div");
var h2 = new HtmlElement("h2");
var childDiv = new HtmlElment("div");

h2.InnerText = "hello world";

childDiv.Children.Add(LabelMessageToTeacher);
childDiv.Children.Add(TextBoxMessageToTeacher);
// add the rest of the nested controls

div.Children.Add(h2);
div.Children.Add(childDiv);
```

Comment: You can expand on the subject?

Comment: HtmlElement constructor does not get elements

Answer (score 0):

Well I reckon You could use "asp:literal" and put into clean HTML
Something like

literal1.Text = "HTML(divs,classes etc.)"

panel.Controls.Add(literal1);

panel.Controls.Add(YourControls);

literal2.text="Closing tags here"

panel.Controls.Add(literal2);

But it can't be the best method to resolve this.